# Starting Sikuli from Python returns error

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I want to run Sikuli for automating windows application using Python. I am new to Sikuli. Actually I have installed Sikuli by using `pip install sikuli`. And then I tried to import it in my Python file as given below:

```
from sikuli import *
print("Working")
```

but when i run it using 'python sikuliTest.py', I get the following error as given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sikuliTest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sikuli import *
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7-     win32.egg\sikuli\__init__
.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sikuli import *
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sikuli-0.1-py2.7-     win32.egg\sikuli\sikuli.p
y", line 15, in <module>
    from jnius import autoclass
  File "d:\users\deepak-ra\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-4xytd2\jnius- 1.1.dev0
-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "d:\users\deepak-ra\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-4xytd2\jnius-  1.1.dev0
-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\jnius.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\users\deepak-ra\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-4xytd2\jnius-1.1.dev0
-py2.7-win32.egg.tmp\jnius\jnius.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Am not sure whether I had installed it correctly or where I have done the mistake. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Sikuli is using Jython and cannot be run directly from Python. If you want to use Python syntax to create scripts using Sikuli start reading [here](http://www.sikulix.com/quickstart.html). Have a look at section 3 "How do I set up SikuliX".

For any specific questions/issues use the [Sikuli Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/sikuli).